# Find -type d with no subfolders

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find, path-finding

Good morning !

This is a simple one I believe, but I am still a noob :)

I am trying to find all folders with a certain name. I am able to do this with the command

```
find /path/to/look/in/ -type d | grep .texturedata
```

The output gives me lots of folders like this :

```
/path/to/look/in/.texturedata/v037/animBMP
```

But I would like it to stop at .texturedata :

```
/path/to/look/in/.texturedata/
```

I have hundreds of these paths and would like to lock them down by piping the output of grep into `chmod 000`

I was given a command with the argument `-dpe` once, but I have no idea what it does and the Internet has not be able to help me determine it's usage

Thanks you very much for your help !

Comment: Why do you use find if the name of the directory seems to be fixed and well known?

Comment: Can you please clarify if there is a possibility of having `/path/to/look/in/somedir/.texturedata` and you would want to change its permission. Otherwise your statement seems ambiguous and we are playing **guess game** !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to find all folders with a certain name. I am able to do
>   this with the command find /path/to/look/in/ -type d | grep
>   .texturedata

No need to `grep` output of `find` to look for specific directory name. `-name` option of `find` will do the same job.

```
find /path/to/look/in/ -type d -name '.texturedata'
```

---

> I would like it to stop at .texturedata

`-prune` option is quite suitable for this requirement

```
find /path/to/look/in/ -type d -name '.texturedata' -prune
```

---

> I have hundreds of these paths and would like to lock them down by
>   piping the output of grep into chmod 000

Try using `find` with `-exec` option

```
find /path/to/look/in/ -type d -name '.texturedata' -exec chmod 000 {} \; -prune
```

More efficient approach would be to pipe output of `find` using `xargs`

```
find /path/to/look/in/ -type d -name '.texturedata' -prune -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 000
```

**TEST**

```
$ tree -pa
.
|-- [drwxrwxrwx]  .texturedata
|   `-- [drwxrwxrwx]  .texturedata
|-- [drwxrwxrwx]  dir1
|   |-- [drwxrwxrwx]  .texturedata
|   |   `-- [-rwxrwxrwx]  file2
|   `-- [drwxrwxrwx]  dir11
|       `-- [-rwxrwxrwx]  file111
|-- [drwxrwxrwx]  dir2
|   `-- [drwxrwxrwx]  .texturedata
|       `-- [-rwxrwxrwx]  file3
|-- [drwxrwxrwx]  dir3
|   `-- [-rwxrwxrwx]  file4
`-- [-rwxrwxrwx]  file1

8 directories, 5 files
$ find . -type d -name '.texturedata' -prune -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 000
$ tree -pa
.
|-- [d---------]  .texturedata [error opening dir]
|-- [drwxrwxrwx]  dir1
|   |-- [d---------]  .texturedata [error opening dir]
|   `-- [drwxrwxrwx]  dir11
|       `-- [-rwxrwxrwx]  file111
|-- [drwxrwxrwx]  dir2
|   `-- [d---------]  .texturedata [error opening dir]
|-- [drwxrwxrwx]  dir3
|   `-- [-rwxrwxrwx]  file4
`-- [-rwxrwxrwx]  file1

7 directories, 3 files
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
find /path/to/look/in/ -type d -name .texturedata -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 000
```

or

```
find /path/to/look/in/ -type d -name .texturedata -exec chmod 000 {} \;
```

No need to use `grep`. The above will only change the permissions of `.texturedata`, not its children, provided no directory in `.texturedata` is also named `.texturedata`. And it will find all `.texturedata` inside `/path/to/look/in`.

Comment: This will not stop at the level of .texturedata

Comment: Looks like it works ! Didn't think it would be this simple ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Never forget to use `find -print0` with `xargs -0` to avoid weird path name caveats

Comment: The second version with exec is horrible, it will start a new chmod process for every directory passing the test.

Comment: @Mithrandir I think, like  @jkshah that the OP does not really want to stop at `/path/to/look/in/.texturedata/` otherwiser a single `chmod` would have sufficed.

Comment: @damienfrancois: hence the the 'But I would like it to stop at .texturedata' in the question?????

Comment: @Mithrandir I share @ jkshah's opinion. See comments in the other response

Comment: And I trust the OP's only comment... :)

Comment: Yes, well if I 'chmod 000' the .texturedata folders it is fine. So a single 'chmod' did the trick ! Thanks a lot to all for your input !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-quit` option in gnu find with `-exec`:

```
find /path/to/look/in/ -type d -name ".texturedata" -exec chmod 000 '{}' \; -quit
```

Comment: `-maxdepth 1` would not give proper output if found dir is more deeper. e.g. `/path/to/look/in/dir/.texturedata`. I believe OP just don't want to find further deep the hierarchy once desired dir is hit.

Comment: @jkshah: Yes I know `-maxdepth 1` will do that but OP wrote: **`But I would like it to stop at .texturedata :

/path/to/look/in/.texturedata/`**

Comment: If `/path/to/look/in/` is really a path with 4 subdirs, and the OP does not want to go further than `/path/to/look/in/.texturedata/`, then the correct answer would be `chmod 000 /path/to/look/in/.texturedata`

Comment: I agree but I think that statement is ambiguous and he actually meant not traverse further down the hierarchy once `.texturedata` hit, not necessarily at depth level 1. Let OP decide what he wants.

Comment: @jkshah: ok I agree that probably OP wrote that by mistake. I updated my find command with `-quit` which will stop after first match.

Comment: @anubhava I still have a concern and counter example with `-quit` but won't discuss till OP clarifies the question. All we are doing is playing **guess game**

Comment: @jkshah: That is fine, let OP take his/her time. Also do you believe `-quit` doesn't work as it is meant to?

Comment: @anubhava No, I don't mean `-quit` doesn't work. but what if there are two paths let's say `/path/dir1/.texturedata/` and `/path/dir2/.texturedata/` and lots of hierarchy under? `-quit` will change permission only for first occurrence and quit command. I believe OP would want all such dir but not those which are down the hierarchy. Again it's guess and more general scenario.

Comment: @anubhava I found that `-prune` option is more suitable here. Try replacing `-quit` with `-prune` and it worked very well for this requirement in all scenarios at-least for me.